# Подскажите регулярку на PHP для строки без двух точек подряд

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется регулярка вот такого вида (цифры, буквы, подчёркивание, скобочки, тире):

```
[A-Za-z0-9_\-\(\)]+
```

Не могу понять как её модифицировать, чтоб она не пропускала строки в которых в любом месте есть две точки подряд...

По идее должно добавиться что-то в духе:

```
^[\\.\\.]
```

Но у меня в голове синтаксис JS'ных регулярок перемешался с PHP'шными, не могу добиться нужного результата.

Comment: ```preg_match('/\.{2,}/',$str)==false;```

Comment: А как это с тем что уже есть совместить? Что-то типа [A-Za-z0-9_\-\(\)[\.{2,}]]

Comment: ```^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\(\)]+\.?)+$```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает, хоть я и не понимаю как...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И в PHP, и в JavaScript можно воспользоваться блоком предварительного просмотра `(?!.*\.\.)` / `(?![\w\W]*\.\.)`:

```php
/^(?!.*\.\.)[A-Za-z0-9_().-]+$/       // Для однострочных текстов
/^(?!.*\.\.)[A-Za-z0-9_().-]+$/s      // Для многострочных текстов 
/^(?![\w\W]*\.\.)[A-Za-z0-9_().-]+$/  // Для многострочных текстов
```

А так как `[A-Za-z0-9_]` эквивалентен `\w`, вы можете использовать

```php
/^(?!.*\.\.)[\w().-]+$/       // Для однострочных текстов
/^(?!.*\.\.)[\w().-]+$/s      // Для многострочных текстов 
/^(?![\w\W]*\.\.)[\w().-]+$/  // Для многострочных текстов
```

Есть ещё один сценарий, когда нужно не пропускать строки с переводом строки (LF, "line feed") в конце:

```php
/^(?!.*\.\.)[\w().-]+$/sD  // Для многострочных текстов, в конце не должно быть LF
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!.*\.\.)` - негативный блок предварительного просмотра, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу после текущей позиции находится ноль и более (как можно более) любых символов, а затем `..`
- `[\w().-]+` - одна и более букв, цифр, символов нижнего подчёркивания, круглых скобок, точки и дефиса
- `$` - конец строки.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/fN0f8V/2).

Comment: Разве скобки () для регулярок в PHP не надо тоже экранировать вот так вот: \\(\\)

Comment: @Никитос В символьных классах не надо. Вне символьных классов — обязательно.

Answer (score -1):

Выбирай:

```
^((?!\.\.).)*$
^(?!.*\.\.)
```

Comment: а выбор из предложенных двух вариантов, видимо, следует основывать на подкидывании монеты? может лучше всё-таки немножко объяснений добавить?

Comment: Да и незачем повторять то, что уже было опубликовано в другом ответе.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ну если устраивают оба, то можно и монетку подкинуть, хотя я бы брал второй как более простой. Но ведь первый более универсальный и позволяет его встроить в более сложную регулярку, как фрагмент, ограниченный чем-то ещё вместо начала и конца строки).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ну первой регулярки в твоём ответе нет. Ну и я ответил чисто на вопрос про две точки, а ты пытался доугадать требования вопроса. Приведённый в вопросе набор символов не предполагает наличие точек вообще, а значит и двух подряд там быть не может (если добавить крышку с долларом). Так что для меня странно пытаться дописать ту регулярку при том, что поддержку точек в неё дописать не просили. Впрочем ладно, держи плюсик.

Comment: `^((?!\.\.).)*$` тут не является правильным ответом. Второе — часть правильного ответа, уже описанное в моём ответе.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, если в первом заменить точку на `[A-Za-z0-9_().-]`, то оно тоже станет тем, что ты считаешь "правильным ответом" ;)